# Google Apps SSO with Windows Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, federation

I am trying to configure Windows Azure AD with Google Apps using their SSO facility. I had gone through the guide provided by Azure and configured Azure AD with Google Apps. But when I try to sign in to my account using Azure Ad, I am given an error saying Federation Failed.

Below is the error code,

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: c58fff4e-47a2-4500-a99e-0014cb4d5436
Timestamp: 2014-09-08 20:01:54Z
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier google.com was not found in the directory d7b703c2-7ca4-4008-9a41-84eb4c3ed46c

What could be the reason and how can I fix this. Kindly help on the above.

Thanks, 
CloudExplorer

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug.  I opened a support request with Windows Azure support and we performed a couple hours of troubleshooting steps.  They confirmed the issue and raised a bug.

## Summary

As per the following article, tried to click on the ‘Google Apps’ tile in the access panel account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications. Same error.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/10/04/an-update-on-dates-pricing-and-sharing-some-cool-data.aspx

01/01/2015 23:42 | Raised a bug with the backend team, ID: 3996896

Waiting for an update from Microsoft, will post back here if the issue gets resolved.